# Revoking the APNS certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

In my app i am using APNS. I've made certificates but i am confuse to use. 
I am getting the following error.

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14094414:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate revoked

I want to delete the certificates and app id and want to generate new ones. My app is not ready for app store now. Can i do this?  Or it will create problem for me. Please help me. 
If possible please guide me how can i do this smoothly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problems deleting certificates and generating new ones. You are not limited to just one certificate per account. In fact, you should delete your push certificates from the Apple developer member center and start fresh if you aren't thoroughly familiar with how push certificates work.

[The simplest tutorial I know off of the top of my head is here.](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) Go there and follow steps 1 - 4. [Another good tutorial is here.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) While that tutorial is for iOS 6, the steps for generating a fresh certificate are identical for iOS 7.

This will help you get rid of all errors. You will then have to re-upload certificates to your push notifications provider.